# Separate nested python dictionary into 2 separate dictionaries

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

So I have a nested dictionary in python as follows:

```
{'name': 'Waffles',
 'subCategories': [{'menu': [{'name': 'Fig & Honey with Fresh Cream','price': 120},
                             {'name': 'Toffeed Banana', 'price': 110}],
                    'name': 'Sweet',
                    'description': 'Sweet and yummy'},

                   {'menu': [{'name': 'Mushroom Cheese Gratin','price': 175},
                             {'name': 'Pepper Chicken Waffle', 'price': 180}],
                   'name': 'Savoury'
                   'description' : 'Salty and yummy'}]
}
```

What I am looking at is to separate out the dict into 2 dicts as follows:

```
{'name': 'Waffles(Sweet)',
 'menu': [{'name': 'Fig & Honey with Fresh Cream','price': 120},
          {'name': 'Toffeed Banana', 'price': 110}],
 'description' : 'Sweet and yummy'} 

{'name': 'Waffles(Savoury)',
 'menu': [{'name': 'Mushroom Cheese Gratin','price': 175},
          {'name': 'Pepper Chicken Waffle', 'price': 180}],
 'description': 'Salty and yummy'}
```

Note that the **name** key is a combination of the same key in the outer and inner dicts

What would be the best way to tackle this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoping the code is self explantory!!

```
import pprint
d = {'name': 'Waffles',
     'subCategories': [
         {'menu': [{'name': 'Fig & Honey with Fresh Cream','price': 120},
                             {'name': 'Toffeed Banana', 'price': 110}],
                    'name': 'Sweet',
                    'description': 'Sweet and yummy'},
         {'menu': [{'name': 'Mushroom Cheese Gratin','price': 175},
                             {'name': 'Pepper Chicken Waffle', 'price': 180}],
                   'name': 'Savoury',
                   'description' : 'Salty and yummy'}]
}

menu = []
for category in d.get('subCategories', []):
    category['name'] =  "{}({})".format(d['name'], category.get('name', ''))
    menu.append(category)


pprint.pprint(menu)
```

and the sample output

```
[{'description': 'Sweet and yummy',
  'menu': [{'name': 'Fig & Honey with Fresh Cream', 'price': 120},
           {'name': 'Toffeed Banana', 'price': 110}],
  'name': 'Waffles(Sweet)'},
 {'description': 'Salty and yummy',
  'menu': [{'name': 'Mushroom Cheese Gratin', 'price': 175},
           {'name': 'Pepper Chicken Waffle', 'price': 180}],
  'name': 'Waffles(Savoury)'}]
```

Comment: this is really nice..if not a problem..can you help explain how d.get('subCategories', []) is different from just d.get('subCategories') ?

Comment: `d.get('subCategories', [])`  returns an empty list when the key 'subCategories' does not exist , thus making sure the for loop is not broken, if no default value is mentioned, the `get` method return `None` (`dict.get(key, default=None)`).

Answer (score 1):

This is the code to do what you ask. Note that it can be optimized, but was left as is for readability.

```
dict = #your dictionary
# list to hold your new dictionaries (if there are more than one)
dict_list = []
# loop to extract
for item in dict['subCategories']:
    d = {}
    id = item['name']
    # this could be made more compact
    d.update({'name':'Waffles('+id+')'})
    d.update({'menu':item['menu']})
    d.update({'description':item['description']})
    dict_list.append(d)
# print new dictionaries
for i in dict_list:
    print(i)
```

Note that the program could be made more robust to handle arbitrary yamls (or json, I don't know what format this dictionary came from) if needed. Here the keys for extraction are hard coded.

Best of luck!

ps: there was formatting error in your starting dictionary